# Passing multiple objects to controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've started working with MVC4 + EF and faced the problem with Image uploading:
I want to save the image path to DB, but the actual file to `~/App_Data/`

I need to pass an "`HttpPostedFileBase`" and my custom "`Image`" objects to "`Create`" controller. I've created a class "`ImageUpload`" to pass both objects.

"`Image`" class:

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

"ImageUpload" class:

```
public class ImageUpload
{
    public Image image { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MvcBannikov.Models.ImageUpload

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Image", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>New Photo</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <p>Name:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.image.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.image.Name)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <p>Path:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.file, new { type = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.file)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

"`Create`" method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ImageUpload image)
{
     ......................
}
```

The problem is that `ImageUpload` object is `NULL` :(((

The reason why I need a file and the Image class is that Image class have a Department ID - I need that `id`.

Maybe you know another solution how I can pass a `DepartmentId` with the file together?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Create one more extra layer, make it your ViewModel.
Instead of this class set up all the fields you need to process, e.g.: Image class, etc.
And assign this ViewModel to your View as your MVC's "Model"

PS
this solution only gives you the idea of how to work with multiple Models at once. However it does not cover the correctness of your Models

Comment: Thank you for reply. My ImageUpload class was created as a ViewModel of some kind and I think I understand the basic idea but it doesn't work with the code I created. I've created a strongly-typed view to this "Create" action, but it's NULL anyway. Maybe the problem in my View?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Just change your controller to use only your `Image` model and get your file from your `Request` Object

**Controller :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Image image)
{
     HttpPostedFileBase myFile = Request.Files["file"];
     ......................
}
```

Didn't check the code, but i remember doing this once.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in this case myFile is null. Your answer helped me somehow though. I can take a Department Id from

Uri uri = Request.Url;

uri in this case == http://localhost:18388/Image/Create?departmentId=3

I can parse this string but something telling me that this is a "bad" approach, or no?

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. I've added HiddenFor for Department Id and now getting results